# StoryBoard issue in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, xcode6.1

I am having the project which is successfully done the project in `Xcode 5.1` using story board, I am running the project in `Xcode 6.1` now its showing the error in `Xcode 6.1`. I am getting the error as

```
Main_iPhone.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances
```

How to resolve this error and make the project run in `64 bit` and support to `iOS8`

Hoping for the right answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 6 supports static tableviews only inside a UITableViewController, general purpose UIViewController with static UITableView inside are not allowed anymore.

To resolve you can follow 2 ways:
- put all the static content inside arrays, declare a table delegate and load all the content runtime. (Best solution)
- Put your static content inside a UITableViewController and embed it with a Container View inside your UIViewController (this will be more tricky if you have to intercept events of static table)